# How to set the coordinate points dynamically in svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to create a triangle using SVG. I did so by following the [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/polygon-element.html). But the problem is that the coordinates are hardcoded.
In the canvas I use to do it by getting the width and height from javascript.

in canvas

```
var width = document.getElementById('intro2').offsetWidth;
var height=document.getElementById('intro2').offsetHeight;
var canvas = document.getElementById("intro2canvas");
canvas.width=width;
canvas.height=height;
if (canvas.getContext) {
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(242,91,32,0.45)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(width/1.66,height);
ctx.lineTo(0,height);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle="rgba(242,91,32,0.45)";
ctx.fill();
```

How to get the height and width value so that I can use that in SVG ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically create and set width and height of svg as follows:

```
function createSVG(){
    svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
    svg.setAttribute('version', '1.1');
    svg.setAttribute('id', 'id'); //id for reffering your svg
    var canvas = document.getElementById('id'); //id of your container element
    width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
            svg.setAttribute('height', height);
            svg.setAttribute('width', width);
            canvas.appendChild(svg);
            //return svg;
}
```

for adding polygons dynamically you can use a function like

```
function drawPoly(points, fill, stroke) {

    var poly = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","polygon");
    poly.setAttribute("points", points);
    poly.setAttribute("stroke", stroke);
    poly.setAttribute('fill', fill);

    svg.appendChild(poly); //where svg is referring to your svg element

            // return poly;
}
```

Afterwards you can create the polygon in tutorial dynamically like

```
drawPoly("10,0  60,0  35,50","#cc3333","#660000");
```

**UPDATE: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGryh/2)**

**UPDATE: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGryh/3/) with auto resize**

Comment: the function should be in inside svg tag or inside js

Comment: the thing is like i need to put the points value as width/1.5 or something like that ,then the function you have mentioned are to be written inside the <svg> or in javascript

Comment: it should be in javascript.

Comment: that what idont want to do as the resolution will vary ,the polygon will also vary i guess,thats why i want to use width/1.5,height/1.8 ,values like that so that it will remain in proportion in any screen

Comment: var poly = drawPoly("10,0  60,0  35,50", "#cc3333", "#660000");

other than this i want to use something like  this 

 var poly = drawPoly("0,0  width/1.66,height 0,height", "#cc3333", 
"#660000");

which i can not achieve
other than that your solution is absolutely correct to me

Comment: @N.Nihar check by resizing this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SGryh/3/

for preserving proportion look in svg view box property: webdesign.about.com/od/svg/a/svg-viewbox-attribute.htm or redraw the svg accordingly on window.resize