# How to convert SVG code into a javascript function that creates it for google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, svg

I have generate a svg icon and i want to manipulate the fill colour. I just don't have idea how to convert this svg code into manipulatable javascript function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="512px" height="512px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#48B3CC" d="M256,0C149.969,0,64,85.969,64,192c0,43.188,14.25,83,38.313,115.094L256,512l153.688-204.906
C433.75,275,448,235.188,448,192C448,85.969,362.031,0,256,0z M256,320c-70.688,0-128-57.312-128-128c0-70.687,57.313-128,128-128
c70.688,0,128,57.313,128,128C384,262.688,326.688,320,256,320z"/>
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="255.5" cy="191.5" r="129"/>
</svg>
```

and how to convert into this applicable code

```
var icon = function (c) {
        return {
            path: 'M256,0C149.969,0,64,85.969,64,192c0,43.188,14.25,83,38.313,115.094L256,512l153.688-204.906C433.75,275,448,235.188,448,192C448,85.969,362.031,0,256,0z M256,320c-70.688,0-128-57.312-128-128c0-70.687,57.313-128,128-128c70.688,0,128,57.313,128,128C384,262.688,326.688,320,256,320z',
            fillColor: c,
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            scale: 1,
            strokeColor: '',
            strokeWeight: 14
        }
    };
```

I failed to know where to put the `<circle>` tag into this code. Appreciate if someone can help

Comment: Check this post 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300573/how-to-set-the-coordinate-points-dynamically-in-svg/22300794#22300794

Comment: do you want to generate the whole svg dynamically, or just want to change an elements fill color?

Comment: just the fill color. Not sure how to put the `circle` tag and scale it nicely

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically adding svg elements using js, you need to create svg elements.

the following function returns an svg circle that you can append to your sag element :

```
function drawCircle(cx, cy, r, fill, id //optional) {
    var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","circle");
    circle.setAttribute("cx", cx);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", cy);
    circle.setAttribute("r", 0);
    circle.setAttribute("fill", fill);

    if (typeof (id) !== 'undefined') {
    circle.setAttribute("id", id);
    }
            return circle;
}
```

Then you can add the circle to your svg like

```
 var circle = drawCircle(255.5, 191.5, 129, "#FFFFFF", 'myCircle');
 svg.appendChild(circle); //  where svg refers to your actual svg element
```

Later you can change its attributes using the id, as follows

```
var circle =document.getElementById('myCircle');
circle.setAttribute("fill", 'new color');
```

Comment: if look at my problem above, i cannot simply apply it on svg because i used google map

Comment: Do you want to change fill on individual svg markers, or all of them that use this specific svg path+circle?

Answer (score 0):

To add the circle to the google icon path, you could convert it to a circular arc. However, I think the best approach would be to create individual svg files for each icon fill. Rather than building an svg path icon, you would use an svg file as follows (note-you will have to change the viewBox, or build in Illustrator, so the svg will be the size of the icon):

```
MyGreenSVG = {
    url: 'greenFill.svg',
    size: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 5)
    };

 MyRedSVG = {
    url: 'redFill.svg',
    size: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 5)
    };
```

Then, when you want to add a marker:

```
    GreenMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: location,
        map: MyMap,
        icon: MyGreenSVG
    });

   RedMarker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: location,
        map: MyMap,
        icon: MyRedSVG
    });
```

Comment: i have a few other colours and not just two. Sorry